# LVM snapshot restored node is added as member with invalid config error

Tags: mongodb

Below is the issue :-
--> Lets say NODE 2 is restored using lvm sanpshot backup of primary 
--> If mongodb is running on primary, lets say NODE1. Then Node2 is added as member of replica set. Then below error is thrown

> ***REPL [ReplicationExecutor] Error in heartbeat request to NODE2 ; InvalidReplicaSetConfig: Our replica set configuration is invalid or
>   does not include us***

**and primary NODE1 starts initial sync with secondary despite of fact that data is already present in NODE 2 data directory and NODE2 is in startup phase**

---> If mongodb is running on primary, lets say NODE1.We shutdown NODE1 using **

> db.shutdowServer({force:true}) command.

** 
Then, We, start NODE1 and add NODE2 as secondary, It becomes Secondary and inital SYNC is avoided, but throw below error

**

> 018-01-19T12:57:50.229-0500 I NETWORK [thread1] connection accepted
>   from NODE2:60570 #49 (5 connections now open)
>   2018-01-19T12:57:50.229-0500 I REPL [ReplicationExecutor] Error in
>   heartbeat request to NODE2:27021; InvalidReplicaSetConfig: Our replica
>   set configuration is invalid or does not include us
>   2018-01-19T12:57:50.230-0500 I REPL [ReplicationExecutor] Error in
>   heartbeat request to NODE2:27021; InvalidReplicaSetConfig: Our replica
>   set configuration is invalid or does not include us
>   2018-01-19T12:57:50.231-0500 I - [conn49] end connection NODE2:60570
>   (6 connections now open) 2018-01-19T12:57:50.231-0500 I NETWORK
>   [thread1] connection accepted from NODE2:60574 #50 (5 connections now
>   open) 2018-01-19T12:57:50.231-0500 I REPL [ReplicationExecutor] Error
>   in heartbeat request to NODE2:27021; InvalidReplicaSetConfig: Our
>   replica set configuration is invalid or does not include us
>   2018-01-19T12:57:50.233-0500 I - [conn50] end connection NODE2:60574
>   (6 connections now open) 2018-01-19T12:57:50.236-0500 I NETWORK
>   [thread1] connection accepted from NODE2 #51 (5 connections now open)
>   2018-01-19T12:57:50.237-0500 I - [conn51] end connection NODE2:60578
>   (6 connections now open) 2018-01-19T12:57:52.232-0500 I REPL
>   [ReplicationExecutor] Member NODE2:27021 is now in state SECONDARY

**

The question is why this error is comming in mongo always and and what can be done to avoid that. 
**

> REPL [ReplicationExecutor] Error in heartbeat request to NODE2 ;
>   InvalidReplicaSetConfig: Our replica set configuration is invalid or
>   does not include us

**

**Is there a way i can add node as secondary without doing shutdownServer command and intialsync using LVM SNAPSHOT BACKUP**

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how to properly format and ask a question!

Comment: @UbdusSamad.. This was first time i was posting. Thanks for suggestions. Hope the edited post would help.

Comment: The cleaner, nicer, and professional your question looks, more the response it gets around here. Same goes for your answer, a good well written and formatted answer may get more upvotes than a great poorly written answer as people here are busy (As using SO is just their hobby) and they prefer well written and easy to read answers.